# Merge arrays inside array dynamically which have the same keys

Tags: php, arrays

I am using PHP 5.6. I have an array like this:

```
 $array = [
    0 => [
        'johndrake@gmail.com' => [
            'email' => 'johndrake@gmail.com',
            'firstname' => 'john',
            'lastname' => 'drake',
            'food' => 'burger',
        ],
    ],
    1 => [
        'johndrake@gmail.com' => [
            'email' => 'johndrake@gmail.com',
            'firstname' => 'john',
            'lastname' => 'drake',
            'drink' => 'coke',
        ],
    ],
    2 => [
        'samwin@gmail.com' => [
            'email' => 'samwin@gmail.com',
            'firstname' => 'sam',
            'lastname' => 'win',
            'food' => 'pizza',
        ],
    ],
    3 => [
        'samwin@gmail.com' => [
            'email' => 'samwin@gmail.com',
            'firstname' => 'sam',
            'lastname' => 'win',
            'drink' => 'pepsi',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Let's say that "food" and "drink" are categories and they can differ depending on how the questionnaire was setup. So there could in fact be "food", "drink", and "dessert" for example. As you can see, there is an array for each person, for each category. What I would like to do is to merge the arrays by each person so that it will instead show up with the following:

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        'johndrake@gmail.com' => [
            'email' => 'johndrake@gmail.com',
            'firstname' => 'john',
            'lastname' => 'drake',
            'food' => 'burger',
            'drink' => 'coke', // Merged
        ],
    ],
    1 => [
        'samwin@gmail.com' => [
            'email' => 'samwin@gmail.com',
            'firstname' => 'sam',
            'lastname' => 'win',
            'food' => 'pizza',
            'drink' => 'pepsi', // Merged
        ],
    ],
];
```

I have looked at `array_merge` as well as `array_merge_recursive`, however from everything that I've read, you have to specify the arrays in order to merge them, for example it has to be `array_merge(array[0], array[1])`. As you can see, I can't exactly do this because there could be 2,3 or even 4 arrays per person which have to be merged together.

So how do I dynamically merge the arrays for each person so that it shows all their information together?

Comment: simply traverse it in a loop and generate the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly as the result you asked for and it feels pretty messy, but it might be something you can work further with :)

```
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $answers) {
    foreach ($answers as $email => $values) {
        if (!isset($result[$email])) {
            $result[$email] = $values;
            continue;
        }
        $result[$email] = array_merge($result[$email], $values);
    }
}
```

And the result:

```
$result === [
    'johndrake@gmail.com' => [
        'email' => 'johndrake@gmail.com',
        'firstname' => 'john',
        'lastname' => 'drake',
        'food' => 'burger',
        'drink' => 'coke',
    ],
    'samwin@gmail.com' => [
        'email' => 'samwin@gmail.com',
        'firstname' => 'sam',
        'lastname' => 'win',
        'food' => 'pizza',
        'drink' => 'pepsi',
    ],
]
```

Comment: This is not the result he wants

Comment: Thanks @martindilling. Your answer gave me the result that I needed. I hope that my proposed result in my question didn't confuse anyone.

Comment: @Mojtaba, I know it's not exactly what he requested, and I started my answer stating that :) But when the result are merged together so the emails are unique I can't really see any reason for the extra layer of wrapping :)

Comment: @Dillon, after formatting your arrays a bit it was a lot easier to see what you meant. Try to do that yourself next time, makes it easier for people to quickly help you ;)
And I'm glad you could use my answer :)

Comment: @martindilling, great

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$originalArray=array (
        0 => array ('johndrake@gmail.com' => array ('email' => 'johndrake@gmail.com', 'firstname' => 'john', 'lastname' => 'drake', 'food' => 'burger')),
        1 => array ('johndrake@gmail.com' => array ('email' => 'johndrake@gmail.com', 'firstname' => 'john', 'lastname' => 'drake', 'drink' => 'coke')),
        2 => array ('samwin@gmail.com' => array ('email' => 'samwin@gmail.com', 'firstname' => 'sam', 'lastname' => 'win', 'food' => 'pizza')),
        3 => array ('samwin@gmail.com' => array ('email' => 'samwin@gmail.com', 'firstname' => 'sam' ,'lastname' => 'win', 'drink' => 'pepsi'))
);
$tempArray=array();
$newArray=array();
foreach($originalArray as $key=>$val){
    $valKey=key($val);
    if(isset($tempArray[$valKey])){
        $newArray[]=array_merge($tempArray[$valKey],$val[$valKey]);
    }
    else{
        $tempArray[$valKey]=$val[$valKey];
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($newArray);
```